# Object.create and inheritance

Tags: javascript, node.js, inheritance, ecmascript-5, object-create

What is the difference between the resulting objects in the following examples:

```
var EventEmitter = require('events').EventEmitter;

var oProto  = Object.create(EventEmitter.prototype);
var oProto2 = Object.create(oProto);

var oConstr  = Object.create(new EventEmitter);
var oConstr2 = Object.create(oConstr);
```

I suppose `oConstr` and `oConstr2` will have any properties set in the `EventEmitter` constructor, but is there any other meaningful difference?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code is misleading. you use the term `oConstr` when it's not a constructor function.

```
oProto -> EventEmitter.prototype -> Object.prototype -> null
oProto2 -> oProto -> EventEmitter.prototype -> Object.prototype -> null

var temp = new EventEmitter;

oConstr -> temp -> EventEmitter.prototype -> Object.prototype -> null
oConstr2 -> oConstr -> etc
```

The only difference is that `temp` is not just an object that inherits from `EventEmitter` it also has own properties augmented from the call to `EventEmitter.constructor.call(temp)`.

I'd personally recommend you use `EventEmitter.prototype` and ignore `new EventEmitter`

Personally I don't ever inherit from `EventEmitter`, [I mix it in](https://github.com/Raynos/raynos-blog/blob/master/src/data/model.js#L6)